# Scripting Unity3D - Opening door does not stop rotating

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Right.. It's my first time asking a question here so my apologies if I leave any important details out, I'll do my best to give the relevant information.

Here's my problem: I'm using a script for a door to open a cabinet, and one door works just fine. The other door however is mirrored and opens along the same rotation, making it open inwards instead of outwards.
My guess (as a complete beginner, mind you) is that

```
    openRot = new Vector3 (defaultRot.x, defaultRot.y + DoorOpenAngle, defaultRot.z
```

needs to be chaged to a negative DoorOpenAngle (just replacing + with a - to flip the direction of the rotation).
This however has instead made the door spin around incredibly fast and it doesn't stop "opening", it just keeps spinning the full 360 degrees in an infinite loop. The following script is the one for the properly working door, if I was to change the angle to a negative value like in my suggestion above, what else could be the cause of the door never stopping?
 I'm guessing there's another piece of code with a conflict due to trying a simple mirror rotation, sorry if this looks messy according to your own standards, done my best on the formatting.

```
var smooth = 2.0;
var DoorOpenAngle = 90.0;  

private var open : boolean;
private var enter : boolean;  

private var defaultRot : Vector3;
private var openRot : Vector3;  

function Start()  
{
  defaultRot = transform.eulerAngles;
  openRot = new Vector3 (defaultRot.x, defaultRot.y + DoorOpenAngle, defaultRot.z);
}  

//Main function
function Update (){
  if(open)  
  {
    //Open door
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles,
        openRot, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
  }  
  else  
  {
    //Close door
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles,
        defaultRot, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
  }

  if(Input.GetKeyDown("f") && enter){
    open = !open;
  }
}
function OnGUI(){
  if(enter){
    GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2 - 75, Screen.height - 100, 150, 30), "Press 'F' to open the cabinet");
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that's Javascript, not Java. I don't believe Unity uses Java as its scripting language.

Comment: Thanks, actually had no idea there was a difference between the two ;) Changed the title of the question.

Comment: It is UnityScript actually, which is NOT JavaScript (or ECMAScript if we are trying to be precise): http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript

Comment: Wow, had no idea about that either... I'm actually not the one trying to program this, I'm helping a friend. I personally don't have any experience with coding at all, I just read it and understand the logic basically. Thanks for the clarifications about what language it was though. It's not that easy being the middleman for this.

Comment: Can't see why this is working for either open or close. The update loop keeps calling `Slerp` endlessly. deltaTime is the time since the last frame. Try recording the time the "f" key is pressed then `Slerp` based on time passed since that time, rather than deltaTime.

Comment: Once the rotations are similar, there is nothing to Slerp. It'll keep executing, sure, but the distance it moves each iteration becomes so miniscule that it's practically not moving at all. When the number of iterations approaches infinity, they will become identical.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj - oh right, I see the Slerp is starting from the current not original rotation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what [`Slerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) does. You're expecting it to behave more like [`RotateTowards`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html).

`Slerp`, like any *linear interpolation* function, takes two values `from` and `to`, then returns another value that is `t` percent between them. That's very useful, sometimes, but not really what you're trying to do, here.

`RotateTowards`, on the other hand, takes two values `current` and `target`, then rotates `current` toward `target` by up to `maxRadiansDelta` and returns that. This is much closer to the behavior you're looking for.

Since we are dealing with rotation, it'll be easier to use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). The basic concepts are the same.

Suppose you want the door to rotate by 30 degrees per second:

```
//convert euler angles to quaternion
//you can do this earlier, but this is fine for now
var openRotQ = Quaternion.Euler(openRot);

//calculate rotation
var maxDegrees = Time.deltaTime * 30;
var newRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, openRotQ, maxDegrees);

//apply rotation
transform.rotation = newRot;
```

If it's still not working after those changes, it's worth noting that Unity's documentation recommends that you avoid angles above 360 degrees [when working with Euler angles](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html).

You can work around that by building a separate quaternion for each rotation you wish to apply:

```
//compose and apply a separate quaternion for rotation
var rotated = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, DoorOpenAngle, 0);
openRot = rotated.eulerAngles;
```

Comment: Actually I understand just fine what it does, it's Quaternion functions I haven't understood yet ;)   Also like I mentioned in a comment before, I'm not the actual coder.. I'm just the one who tends to understand better what I see, but I'm currently waiting for a shipment since I just moved abroad and as such, I don't have the hardware required to test things on my own. I've been thinking that Quaternion would make more sense but with my lack of knowledge, I just couldn't integrate it properly.

Comment: I added one more piece of advice to my answer. You didn't mention that it's a problem, but it's the only other issue I see from the information given.

Comment: Yeah we're planning on using your answer to work more with the problem tomorrow. Thanks for the detailed information! And we haven't worked with anything above 360 degrees. My first thought was to change 90 to 270 (to stop it at the correct location) but that didn't change the way it rotated. Once we figured out how to flip the direction, the door flipped out completely which made no sense. The first one worked just fine so I saw no reason to start meddling with Quaternion but we'll see how things go.